# Cómo obtener la Inversa de una matriz en código?

Tags: python, álgebra-relacional

Tengo un problema en mi código que aún no encuentro, resulta que se desea obtener la inversa de una matriz nxn utilizando el método Gauss-jordan . Tengo un avance, pero resulta que a la hora de imprimir la matriz de resultados, no me dan los esperados. 
Les dejo un link el cuál tiene el código que he escrito, está en hecho en Python.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12inaI3iL1qM4nESUWcr_ZoqPJcp-lyyI/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Deberías colocar el código en la pregunta, así, si se borra el código, siempre quedará en la pregunta para que la gente que le suceda lo mismo le sirva de auda

Answer (score 0):

Las operaciones de actualización se realizan renglón por renglón, no elemento por elemento.
Ilustrare tu error con un ejemplo, supongamos que quieres obtener la inversa de

```
1 2
3 4
```

En la primera iteracion:
Para obtener el 0 abajo del uno debes multiplicar cada elemento el primer renglón por -3 y sumar elementos correspondientes, el resultado es :

```
1 2 
0 -2
```

La salida de la primera iteracion de tu código es :

```
1 2
0 4
```

Lo que significa que solo estas realizando la operación en el elemento debajo del 1 , cuando la operación debe realizarse sobre todos los elementos del renglón(multiplicar 2  por -3, sumarlo al 4 y sustituir el 4 por el resultado), para empezar.

La parte de codigo que debes cambiar es

```
     matriz[c][j] = (posicion + matriz[c][j])
```

por una que realice la operación sobre todo el renglón, algo como

```
para cada elemento del renglon de abajo
   el -=(posicion/elemento_bajo_posicion)*el_arriba_de_el
```

Aunque no revise la operacion de actualizacion de la matriz identidad, aclaro que lo mismo aplica para ella: cada operacion que realices en matriz debe realizarse en identidad. Renglon por renglon, no elemento por elemento.
Te recomiendo usar numpy, es una librería que te facilita realizar todo tipo operaciones con matrices